# Marks for Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have two maps on different tabs...I am trying to add a location of the business on the map and use a marker...this is my code what do I need to do to make this work? it will not even pull up the map anymore when I put the marker code I have in this code...please no one liners explain what I need to do in order to fix this problem thank!

```
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

   public class Contacts2 extends FragmentActivity {
 private static final String Contacts2 = "Contacts2";

 private GoogleMap contact2Map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts2);

    addtest();

    }

    private void addtest() {

        LatLng position = new LatLng(26.0460563,-80.2517702);
        contact2Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title("text")
        .snippet("text")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
        .position(position));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contacts2map, mMapFragment,Contacts2);
         fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentByTag(Contacts2);

       fmanager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();


    }
```

}

Comment: Where are you initializing contact2Map? Show me your xml.

Comment: Just a  LinearLayout  with <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/contacts2map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts2);

    //Add this line
    contact2Map= ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contacts2map))
        .getMap();

    addtest();

    }
```

Comment: I get thisMultiple markers at this line
 - MapFragment cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - MapFragment cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Change it SupportMapFragment instead.

Comment: Cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Comment: try this,    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
      .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();